# как добавить данные в столбец из другой таблицы если есть дубликаты

Tags: sql, teradata

я хочу вставить в SBX.COR в столбец Prefix данные из Prefix из SBX.HEX для конкретных совпадений, но мой запрос

```
 update SBX.COR sc
set Prefix = (
    select Prefix 
        from SBX.HEX sfh
            where sc.Car = sfh.Car
            and sc.Opex = sfh.Opex
            and sc.Reg = sfh.Reg)
```

выдает

> More than one value was returned by a subquery

как поправить запрос?

Comment: Правильный ответ зависит (1) от того, как именно надо выбрать одно значение из нескольких; (2) от того, какая используется СУБД, включая точную версию.

Comment: Teradata RELEASE,16.20.32.49
VERSION,16.20.32.49
LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE,Standard

Comment: https://docs.teradata.com/r/huc7AEHyHSROUkrYABqNIg/k6fC7ozmhIZZXa315VjJAw

Comment: ответы уже затерли, все равно, спасибо всем ответившим, вариант с max(prefix) помог

Comment: Akina, спасибо!

Comment: Ответ восстановил, раз уж он хотя бы отчасти сработал. Можете отметить принятым, если он вам помог.

Comment: Kromster, а как закрыть? у меня тут только Поделиться, Править, Удалить и Тревога?

Answer (score 0):

Определить *КАК* выбрать из нескольких значений одно правильное.

Т.к. в вопросе не была указана СУБД, то предлагались варианты для MS SQL.
Например, первое попавшееся - `SELECT TOP 1 Prefix ...`, или максимальное - `SELECT MAX(Prefix) ...` и т.п.

Comment: не хочет, пишет TOP N Syntax error: Top N option is not supported in subquery.

Comment: @Alex_B В MSSQL работает. Как вам верно заметили в комментариях - уточняйте о какой СУБД идёт речь в вопросе.

Comment: Teradata RELEASE,16.20.32.49 VERSION,16.20.32.49 LANGUAGE SUPPORT MODE,Standard